# Filtrar por medio de $in y booleano

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy queriendo obtenerme documentos (productos en este caso) usando **find()** con dos filtros, uno que el **estado = true** y otro que la **pertenece a una categoria** (algo que me envían en el request).

Hago el filtro de esta manera (si me trae los productos de una determinada categoría, pero no respeta el estado = true, porque me trae productos que también tiene estado falso)

```
let categorias  = req.body;
Producto.find({ estado: true, "categoria": {$in : categorias} }...
```

Probe poniendo **" "**, en estado como en true, pero tampoco funciona. Que me esta faltando hacer?

Gracias.

Comment: Podrias añadir el Schema de `Producto`? Gracias

Comment: Tal como está tu código debería funcionar sin problemas. Agrega tu esquema de datos para poder ayudarte mejor. Saludos